# how to pass different values in a collection

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-2.11

I am using this code https://github.com/alvinj/ScalaCasbahConnections/blob/master/src/main/scala/casbahtests/MongoFactory.scala

```
object MongoFactory {

  private val SERVER = "localhost"
  private val PORT   = 27017
  private val DATABASE = "finance"
  private val COLLECTION = "stocks"

  val connection = MongoConnection(SERVER)
  val collection = connection(DATABASE)(COLLECTION)

}
```

but here in this code COLLECTION val has "stocks" value means it has only one value what if i want to use different values of collection name how can i modify this code to support different collection names ,please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it must work:

```
def collection(name : String) = connection(DATABASE)(name)
```

Comment: after doing this the functionality of above code remains same ?

Comment: @swaheed replace `collection` field with `collection` function. then pass name what you need in client code.